# How to add a Postgre Database to an existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I created a new Rails project without database (rails new myApp -O). 
How can I add a Postgresql database now ?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `pg` gem to your gemfile.

```
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
```

Then, if you do not have it, you will need a `database.yml` file in your `config` directory so go there and in the config directory create a fole called `database.yml` which should look like this.

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
username: your username for your Postgresql access
password: your password for your Postgresql access
# For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: The name for your **development** database that you created (probably in PGAdmin?)

test:
  <<: *default
  database: The name for your **test** database that you created (probably in PGAdmin?)

production:
  <<: *default
  database: The name for your **production** database that you created (probably in PGAdmin?)
```

Comment: One probably must also add a line that active_record to config/application.rb. Config test generators, maybe. And god knows what else. If it's a brand new app, easier to just regenerate.

Comment: I totally agree, easier to just rebuild if that is an option

Comment: thanks Rockwell and Sergio, I will consider this option (start again the project) but I'll also challenge myself trying to add the db and make things work, I'll probably learn interesting stuff!

Comment: Hopefully my answer gets you there but I could be missing something buried somewhere for sure.